# Uwp How to get the Human Interface Device(HID) service from BluetoothLEDevice

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

First of all, Sorry for my bad English. I'm studying about BluetoothLE under the UWP.
Now, I can pair with my Bluetooth Low-Energy device and i can get services.
And then, I want to get the all characteristics from my Bluetooth(LE) device.

I can get all service's characteristics except Human Interface Device(HID)'s characteristics.
Below is the code get the characteristic( when change the service in combobox event)

```
private async void ServiceListCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var service = (GattDeviceService)((ComboBoxItem)ServiceListCombo.SelectedItem)?.Tag;
            CharacteristicCombo.Items.Clear();

            IReadOnlyList<GattCharacteristic> characteristics = null;
            try
            {
                var accessStatus = await service.RequestAccessAsync();
                if(accessStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed)
                {
                    var result = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
                    if(result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        characteristics = result.Characteristics;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StatusTextBlock.Text = $"{result.Status.ToString()} // Failed";
                        characteristics = new List<GattCharacteristic>();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusTextBlock.Text = $"{accessStatus.ToString()} // Failed2";
                    characteristics = new List<GattCharacteristic>();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception msg)
            {
                StatusTextBlock.Text = $"Exception : {msg.Message}";
                characteristics = new List<GattCharacteristic>();
            }
            foreach(GattCharacteristic c in characteristics)
            {
                CharacteristicCombo.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = Helpers.GetCharacteristicName(c), Tag = c });
            }
            CharacteristicCombo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

I can see all characteristics except HID ( Status : access denied by System )

So what I want to know, How can i get the characteristics in HID Service's characteristics.

I really appreicate ,if you let me know any idea or suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can get all service's characteristics except Human Interface Device(HID)'s characteristics.

Please check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth). At  Support for Bluetooth RFCOMM services [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth#support-for-bluetooth-rfcomm-services) you will find `Human Interface Device` does not support, I'm afraid you can't get hid device characteristics within ble, if you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with Windows Feed Back Hub.